# How do I merge aspx pages MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to merge a sidemenu.aspx on another (Home.aspx, Phone.aspx, Car.aspx... etc) page. How do I do that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have some markup you want to include on every page, without having to copy & paste it onto every page. Is this correct?

Comment: If this were a standard Asp.Net app, it sounds like he wants to use a Master pages scenario where a side menu is in the master page, and Home.aspx, Phone.aspx, and Car.aspx are all nested pages.  However, I don't work with MVC, so I don't know the details well enough to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're a little vague, but I believe you're looking for Master pages, and ContentPlaceHolder controls.  The default website when creating a ASP.NET MVC application is set up with some default ones.

Comment: also, something like "sidemenu.aspx" should probably be "sidemenu.ascx" i.e. a control and not a page

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, You can embed a page into another with a function in the "mvc futures" libraries

In your general page you would have:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Index", "SideMenu"); %>
```

Which will call the action "Index" of the controller "SideMenu" that would return the view "sidemenu.aspx"

This could be added to the master page Agent_9191 is talking about!

Answer (score 0):

While you probably should have a Master Page that can contain your sidebar (this is how I do things), you could also have sidebar as a View User Control, which can be rendered using the Html.RenderPartial helper method.

Answer (score 0):

I had to merge webforms pages with an asp.net mvc page a few months ago.  The most seamless and easiest way I found to do it was using an iFrame:

```
<iframe src="/path/to/file.aspx" frameborder="0" width="970" height="970">
</iframe>
```

It looks like its just part of the site, and the aspx postbacks/viewstate worked perfect with no other changes to asp.net required!